# Go error: Cannot use argument (type []string) as type string in argument

Tags: go, grpc

Trying to get acquainted with go. I want to do something like this:

```
func validation(){
    headers := metadata.New(map[string]string{"auth":"", "abc": "", "xyz" : ""})
    token := headers["auth"]

    data.Add("cookie", token)
}
```

I am getting the following error : `cannot use token (type []string) as type string in argument to data.Add`. Has this error got to do anything with the metadata(map) I have inside the function?

Comment: According to https://github.com/grpc/grpc-go/blob/master/Documentation/grpc-metadata.md result of `metadata.New` is `metadata.MD` which is maps strings to _slices_ of strings, so result of `headers["auth"]` is not `string` but `[]string` (slice) and cannot be used as argument to Add

Answer (score 7):

Token is a `[]string` and the 2nd argument to Add is a `string`. Assuming that you want the first element of the slice and the slice is guaranteed to have at least one element, use this:

```
data.Add("cookie", token[0])
```

If you don't know that there's at least one element in the slice, then protect with an if:

```
if len(token) > 0 {
   data.Add("cookie", token[0])
} else {
   // handle missing value
}
```